# Seadragon(seajax) open specific filterbox after search

Tags: openseadragon, seadragon

In my website i use the seajax pivot viewer to view a large amount of images. So to not search endlessly long for the picture i need i usually use the search box in the view to filter on a specific property of my collection. Now when i press enter it works perfectly and it filters my collection. I could however be possible that multiple properties have the same value so to further filter my search i use the filters beneath the search box. This also works fine.

Now for my question: **Is it possible to open such a filterbox after i press enter, so that the specific values for a certain property are shown?**

I already took a look at it and i belief that i need to do it in the pivot viewer js, however i cannot find the right way to do it. I could not find anything on stackoverflow about it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might also try asking this in the Seajax issues: https://github.com/seajax/seajax/issues

Comment: anyone the developers are not responding aswel